# Value 0 of type class java.util.LinkedHashMap does not correspond to any CQL3 type

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to save a spring entity to Cassandra (2.0.11) using a Cassandra repository. The entity class is as follows:

```
    @Table(value="gs")
    public class GsJsonStore implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7133072282172062535L;
        @PrimaryKey
        private String id;
        @Column(value = "object")
        @CassandraType(type=DataType.Name.MAP)
        private Map<String, String> _object;
        @Column(value = "subject")
        private String _subject;
       //Getter and Setter methods.
    }
```

The code I'm using to save the object:

```
    GsJsonStore gsJsonStore = new GsJsonStore();
    gsJsonStore.setPredicate("Predicate");
    gsJsonStore.setSubject("Subject");
    gsJsonStore.setObject(jsonToMap(jsonNode));
    repository.save(gsJsonStore);
```

The jsonToMap function:

```
    public Map<String,String> jsonToMap(JsonNode json) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> result = mapper.convertValue(json, Map.class);
    return result;
    }
```

I get the following error while storing the object:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

```
Value 0 of type class java.util.LinkedHashMap does not correspond to any CQL3 type
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in Java Driver class TypeCodec in method getDataTypeFor and see what is happening?

Comment: can you add your schema also